# Usage of linux 'column' utility

Tags: bash

I'm trying to generate an N columned table from a file of newline delimited data containing arbitrary text without any whitespace.

For example, I have a file of:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

I would like to display this data in the terminal like so:

```
One        Two
Three      Four
Five       Six
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding how column works, it doesn't seem to allow for anyway to specify the output table structure.

Without any arguments `cat file | column` simply shows them all on their own line just like cat does.

With the -t --table option, it shows them all on the same line `cat file | column -t`

I have tried every combination of arguments along with -t -C left -C right to try and get the output formatted into 2 columns.

I have also come very close to what I want with the `pr` tool: `cat file | pr -t --columns 2`

However, the formatting isn't quite right because some of the cells have whitespace that shifts the alignment off and pr doesn't really offer any other adjustments.

Can anyone offer a native shell/linux solution to take a list of text sequence and display them in a tabular format consisting of N columns?

Comment: No need to waste a `cat` just to redirect input.  `<` should be perfectly fine here.

Comment: "_Some of the cells have whitespace_" is patently false in the input you've provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
```

You can do:

```
$ paste -sd '\t\n' file | column -t
One    Two
Three  Four
Five   Six
```

(Alternatively, `paste -sd '\t\n' - <file | column -t`)

The key is that `paste` alternates between the two characters in the `-d 'xy'` string:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd '!|' -
1!2|3!4|5!6|7!8|9!10
```

So to get two columns with paste, alternate the column separator with the line separator:

```
$ paste -sd '\t\n' file
One Two
Three   Four
Five    Six
```

If you want three columns, you would do:

```
$ paste -sd '\t\t\n' file
One Two Three
Four    Five    Six
```

An alternative to `paste` is this `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ getline line; printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, line }' file
# same output
```

The advantage to `awk` is the formatting between columns and line endings can be multiple characters.

Then to pad those two columns so they are straight, use `column -t` in a pipe after the awk or paste.

Comment: Thanks, while this is a longer pipeline than I wanted, it does get me the output I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're in bash, you may be able to do this without external utilities at all:

```bash
$ cat i
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six

$ printf '%s\t%s\n' $(<i)
One     Two
Three   Four
Five    Six
```

This works because when `printf` runs out of format variables, it just recycles its format to handle additional data. You may run up against limits for very large datasets.

Of course, if you don't like tabstops, you're free to use any format string you want. `'%-20s %s\n'`, for example.

Comment: Works fine in plain shell, too: `xargs printf '%s\t%s\n' <i`

Comment: @TobySpeight .. but in plain shell, you have an unpredictable printf. It *may* support format recycling .. or it may not. Including that in my answer would require a proviso, and since the question was tagged `bash`, I thought a bash-based solution might be appropriate.

Comment: By "plain" shell, I mean a POSIX-conformant one.  In particular, [item 9 of the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13) says, "**The *format* operand shall be reused as often as necessary to satisfy the *argument* operands. Any extra `b`, `c`, or `s` conversion specifiers shall be evaluated as if a null string argument were supplied.**"

Answer (score 3):

The `column` command was originally designed to fit the data to your terminal size.  By default, it fills columns first, up to one less than the number of lines shown on your terminal screen, before moving to the next column.  That's similar to the way text flows in a newspaper, for example.  The few items in your example are not enough to fill the first column, which is why you don't discern the effect.

GNU `column` can also do the opposite by filling rows first, which you can request this with the `-x` option.  You will definitely notice the difference here.  But unless your screen is very narrow, you will also notice that the result is not really what you're looking for: `column` will decide the number of columns for itself (as it also did in the previous mode) based on the width of your terminal in characters and the widths of the various items.

Your best bet for doing this with `column` is to use its table mode, activated via option `-t`.  Here you have to understand that `column` is just going to expect the input to *already* be formatted as a table -- one row per line, with columns separated by whitespace (by default).  `column` has a large number of options for tweaking the result, but basically, it is just going to tidy that up so that it displays as neat columns.

To use `column`'s table mode for your purpose, then, you first need to join adjacent rows of your input.  For example:

```
sed 'N; s/\n/ /g' file | column -t
```

Of course, if your data contain whitespace then you'll need to choose a different field separator.

Beware that even in table mode, `column` is aimed at fitting the output to a fixed-width screen.  You can control the width it uses via command-line option, and you'll likely need to do that if some of your items are lengthy or if you want more than a very few columns.

Comment: Cheers for that explanation about the obscure _column_ command which I have never really understood. However, the man page says that `column` also respects the environment variable `COLUMNS`. I interpret it that we can use this to "lie" about the screen width. However, `COLUMNS=7 column -x inputfile` (using the OP's input) still writes everything in one line, instead of breaking after the 7th character. Why would this be the case?

Comment: @user1934428, per the manual page, "The environment variable `COLUMNS` is used to determine the size of the screen *if no other information is available*".  If you want to try to exercise that case then at minimum you'll want to ensure that the `TERM` environment variable is unset, but I'm unsure whether that will be enough.

Comment: This crucial addition to the clause is missing in my man-page. It just says _The COLUMNS, LANG, LC_ALL and LC_CTYPE environment variables affect the execution of column as  described in environ(7)_; and _environ(7)_ says to this variables: _The user's preferred width in column positions for the terminal.  Utilities such as ls(1) and who(1) use this to format output into columns_. I'm here on MacOS, so it is not surprising that the man pages differ.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what `rs`, the reshape command, excels at.  Here, we just filter through `rs 0 2` (unspecified rows of two columns):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' One Two Three Four Five Six |
    rs 0 2
```

```
One    Two
Three  Four
Five   Six
```

It does the right thing when the entries vary in length, unlike simply formatting with tabs:

```
One           Two
Three         Four
Five          Six
Thirty-Three  Thirty-Four
```

Comment: Looks great, but `rs` is new to me, and its availability seems limited.  I don't have it in my WSL container (oldish SUSE), for example.

Comment: That's a pity.  It's in package `rs` in Debian, but I don't know much about other distros.

Comment: [rs](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) is a BSD utility, not POSIX, and availability on Linux is likely only as a user install.

Answer (score 0):

also check this out :

```
paste - - < file | column -t
```

- `paste - - < file` merges every two lines of the file into a single line, separated by a tab!

output

```
One    Two
Three  Four
Five   Six
```

and if you want to specify a different number of columns,you can modify the `paste` accordingly,for example, to display the data in three columns, you can use:

```
paste - - - < file | column -t
```

or with awk like this

```
awk '{ printf "%-8s", $1 } NR % 2 == 0 { printf "\n" }' file
```

and as you see you can edit the condition in the `NR % 2 == 0` part accordingly,for example, to display the data in three columns, you can use `NR % 3 == 0`!

output

```
One    Two
Three  Four
Five   Six
```